# Facebook iOS SDK: How to handle SKIP button when requesting publish_actions?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, sdk

I have a code to login to Facebook with 'publish_actions' permission.
Here's the snippet:

```
NSArray *facebookPermissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[self facebookPermissions]
                                   defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                      allowLoginUI:YES
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@">>> Permissions available: %@", FBSession.activeSession.permissions);
}];
```

When that method is executed, user will be redirected to Mobile Safari Facebook page and asked whether facebook is allowed to access his/her account.

Screen1:

```
APPNAME would like to access your public profile and friend list.
[CANCEL] [OK]
```

After pressing OK, since we use the openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions method, a second page will appear asking if facebook is allowed to publish stuff on your behalf.

Screen 2:

```
APPNAME would like to post to your friends on your behalf.
[AUDIENCE] [SKIP] [OK]
```

The tricky part is, when user clicks SKIP button, the log in the callback still list `'publish_actions'` as one of the available permissions. Which is incorrect.
The `error` is also nil. How do I detect this properly?

This is the log:

```
2013-07-06 16:35:59.037 FbSandbox[56213:c07] >>> Permissions available: ("publish_actions")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can validate the accepted permissions by [calling](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/permissions) `me/permissions`. This will list the permissions the user has allowed. Cross-reference this list with the permissions you ask for and you'll be able to find out which were accepted and which were skipped.

Comment: This does seem to be the answer. Absolutely terrible API design.